# ios - addtarget to a button in another view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Why doesn't this work? I want the closeBtn in the new view controller to call a method called dismiss: in the current view controller.

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[newVC.closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The dismiss: method is never called in the current view controller. closeBtn is correctly set up as a property in NewViewController and linked in the .xib file.

Comment: Did you check that newVC.closeBtn is not null, just after initWithNibName ?

Comment: The button will be nil until you present the view controller. You should save the target and selector in some ivars and reassign them in the viewDidLoad message. If you need a better explanation, I will add a complete answer.

Comment: By the way, why are you trying to make a not visible controller be target for another controller? (I say not visible because when the button will be visible, the current view controller will be the owner, so not the target). Wouldn't it be better to call the dismiss directly from the newVC, so adding the action to the button directly from IB or in its view did load?

Answer (score 3):

Create the object of the another controller and specify it in addTarget. Give the name of the method in the action parameter. 
i.e anotherController *obj;
[button addTarget:obj action:@selector(MethodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Answer (score -1):

Generally, that is not a good way to deal with methods and UI elements.

However, you can do something like this, though it is ugly.

`[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonPressed:) forControlEvent:UITouchUpInside];`

```
    - (void) yourButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    OtherVC* otherVC = [OtherVC alloc] initWithNibName@"NewViewController"] ...
    [otherVC theDesiredMethod];
   [otherVC release];
}
```

This works but is not really good you are probably better off moving the function into the proper VC.

Hope that helps.